# Adjust a refrigerator on the floor

Tags: floor, refrigerator

My refrigerator stands on the floor unevenly. Its slant is small but enough to make the motor produce unpleasant noises. If I manually tilt the refrigerator a little bit, the noise disappears.

Unfortunately the refrigerator's 'legs' are not adjustable. I tried putting various pieces of plywood under corners. It helps a bit, but finding the right thickness of such piles is hard, and so far I failed to achieve a satisfactory position of the fridge.

What could I use to gradually adjust the vertical position of a large heavy box which is the refrigerator? Some kind of miniature jack screw?

The distance from the floor is about 1/4".

Comment: What's the brand and model #?  I've never seen a fridge without adjustable feet, perhaps you're missing something.  Photo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy, cheap option would be to use shims.

[image]

These are most often used to plumb door jambs, but of course have a ton of uses in construction.

Once you put them in and figure out how far they have to go, mark them and then you can take them out and cut off the excess (either with a hand saw or by scoring with a knife).

Comment: I read the question and was going to suggest tapered shims as a solution. I then scrolled down and saw your picture!!! +1 for this.

Comment: +1 but I would suggest the textured plastic wedges since they are prone to crack over time.